# pgfplots - Tikz: addplot node doesn't appear

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

please I need to draw a curve, but the node of the equation doesn't appear while for other equations it does.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=0cm]
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-3,
        xmax=10,
        ymin=-5,
        ymax=5,
        scale only axis,
        axis lines=middle,
        domain=-2.279018:3,      
        samples=201,
        smooth,   
        clip=true,
        axis equal image=true,
        ]
        \addplot[blue,thick] {sqrt((x+2)^3)}
            node[right] {$C:y^2=(x+2)^3$};
        \addplot[blue,thick] {-sqrt((x+2)^3)};
     \end{axis}
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

thanks.

Comment: I think you have clipped it out of the result with "clip=true"...

Comment: please can you make your code compilable instead of just posting a snippet?  it makes it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add a node in that way, it's placed next to the end of the plot. But the plot ends at x=3, which is at y=11.18. You've set `ymax=5`, so the node is far outside the axis, and is clipped away, as Thruston says. You can move the node to an earlier point along the plot by adding `pos=0.3` (or some other value) to the node options.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=0cm]
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-3,
        xmax=10,
        ymin=-5,
        ymax=5,
        scale only axis,
        axis lines=middle,
        domain=-2:3,
        samples=201,
        smooth,
        clip=true,
        axis equal image=true,
        ]
        \addplot[blue,thick] {sqrt((x+2)^3)}
            node[right, pos=0.3] {$C:y^2=(x+2)^3$};
        \addplot[blue,thick] {-sqrt((x+2)^3)};
     \end{axis}
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thnaks a lot for the explanations

Answer (score 5):

you should restrict y domain for example to `-4.5:4.5`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=0cm]
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-3,    xmax=10,
        scale only axis,
        axis lines=middle,
        domain=-2:2,
        restrict y to domain=-4.5:4.5,
        samples=101,
        smooth,
        axis equal image=true,
        ]
        \addplot[blue,thick] {sqrt((x+2)^3)}
            node[below right] {$C:y^2=(x+2)^3$};
        \addplot[blue,thick] {-sqrt((x+2)^3)};
     \end{axis}
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to place the node differently. In this case, i positionned it at the coordinates x=1, y=1 in axis coordinate system.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=0cm]
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-3,
        xmax=10,
        ymin=-5,
        ymax=5,
        scale only axis,
        axis lines=middle,
        domain=-2:3,
        samples=201,
        smooth,
        clip=true,
        axis equal image=true,
        ]
        \addplot[blue,thick] {sqrt((x+2)^3)}
            node[at={(axis cs:1,1)}] {$C:y^2=(x+2)^3$};
        \addplot[blue,thick] {-sqrt((x+2)^3)};
     \end{axis}
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

> [image]